# How to get object back on update via HttpClient in angular 5

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular5

I updated the contact but can not get back that updated object to update the view, instead I got `{n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1}`.

#### Service getting data from API

```js
export class ContactService {

  url: string = 'http://localhost:3000/contacts/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  async Update(contact: Contact) {
    return await this.http.put(this.url.concat(contact._id), contact);
  }
}
```

#### ContactComponent

```js
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

  async update() {
    const updatingContact = await this.contact.Update(contact);
    updatingContact.subscribe(result => {          
      console.log(result); // {n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1}
    })
  }
}
```

#### API Call

```js
router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const contact = await Contact.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, {
            firstname: req.body.firstname,
            phone: req.body.phone
        });
        res.json(contact);
    }
    catch (err) {
        debug(err.message)
    }
})
```

How do I get the updated object in the `subscribe` method to update the view?

Comment: Your api response is from your backend, configure it to return the object upon update.

Comment: thanks, you saved my time and effort :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be someone else meet with this problem.

#### How I improve my code to get the updated object

```
router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => { // API call

     let contact = await Contact.findById(req.params.id);
     contact.firstname = req.body.firstname;
     contact.phone = req.body.phone;

     res.json(await contact.save());
})
```